# *Google Sheet* Formula to sort and remove duplicate

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Is there anyway in which I can first sort the data date wise and then remove the duplicate names for the same day.

[image]

Comment: Pls share a spreadsheet. People are most likely to not help when there is a lot of data involved but only a screenshot is attached. It is like asking them to create a sheet which they need to fill in by themselves (copy the data of your screenshot) then find the solution. Please make it easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORTN({A2:C, B2:B&A2:A}, 9^9, 2, 4, 0, 2, 1), 9^9, 3)
```